# tabBox width doesn't expand to contain plot

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Starting with the code on this page: [enter link description here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#tabbox), I would like to be able to control the size of the box plot on Tab 1 of the First tabBox.  Hacking in a couple of sliders, and a uiOuput call in the code below, I can now easily control the height and width of the boxplot.  But, while the tabBox nicely expands in height to contain the plot, it does not expand in width.  At high values of width, the plot extends over the boundary of the box.  I see similar results using a simple Box to contain the plot.

Is there a way to change the width of the Box/tabBox to get the desired effect?

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)

  body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
     tabBox(
        title = "First tabBox",
        # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
        id = "tabset1", 
        tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content", uiOutput('UI_test')),
        tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
     ),
     tabBox(
        side = "right", 
        selected = "Tab3",
        tabPanel("Tab1", "Tab content 1"),
        tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2"),
        tabPanel("Tab3", "Note that when side=right, the tab order is reversed.",
                 sliderInput('sldHt', 'Height', min=100, max=500,
                             value=200, step=10),
                 sliderInput('sldWd', 'Width', min=100, max = 500,
                             value=200, step=10)
        )
     )
  ),
  fluidRow(
     tabBox(
        # Title can include an icon
        title = tagList(shiny::icon("gear"), "tabBox status"),
        tabPanel("Tab1",
                 "Currently selected tab from first box:",
                 verbatimTextOutput("tabset1Selected")
        ),
        tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
     )
  )
  )

  shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
     dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
     dashboardSidebar(),
     body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
     # The currently selected tab from the first box
     output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
        input$tabset1
     })
     output$UI_test = renderUI({
        plotOutput('test',
                 height = input$sldHt,
                 width = input$sldWd)
     })
     output$test = renderPlot(
        boxplot(len ~ dose, data = ToothGrowth,
              boxwex = 0.25, at = 1:3 - 0.2,
              subset = supp == "VC", col = "yellow",
              main = "Guinea Pigs' Tooth Growth",
              xlab = "Vitamin C dose mg",
              ylab = "tooth length",
              xlim = c(0.5, 3.5), ylim = c(0, 35), yaxs = "i"))
  }
  )
```

Comment: Wrap the plot in a `mainPanel()` with width setting and see if that works. BTW - if you really want help with working code, you are better off posting minimally working example code here with what your expected behavior is. Asking people to chase external links is not the best way to get help.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to attach the code in the first go round.  I have now added it.  Surely I don't deserve that many down votes for s simple slip which I've now corrected.

Comment: Try the other suggestion and see if it helps. I have had similar width challenges and alignment problems, and that seems to work.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed line 10 to this:  tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content", mainPanel(width=12,uiOutput('UI_test'))),   but that caused the tabBox to completely contract in height and width and not contain the plot at all.  Of course, I may have misinterpreted your suggestion.

Comment: I will have to look up my code tomorrow as to how I fixed it. Perhaps others can help before then.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Gopala How did you fix it ? I'm having the same problem as Kirk